# Excel UDF with ParamArray constraint like SUMIFS

Tags: vba, excel, parameters, paramarray

I am trying to code an Excel UDF with a similar syntax to the builtin `SUMIFS`, that is with a signature like

`Function myUDF(param1 As Type1, ParamArray paramRest() As Variant) As MyType`

but the condition that the ParamArray must have an *even* number of elements (ideally even Typed). Is this at all possible?

For example if you try to enter `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,1,C:C)` into a cell, Excel will complain about using the wrong number of arguments (because the ParamArray would be `Array(Range("B:B"),1,Range("C:C"))` and thus have an odd number of elements). I want the same behaviour for `myUDF`.

Currently I handle it after the fact:

```
If UBound(paramRest) Mod 2 <> 1 Then
    myUDF = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If
```

But that feels "dirty".

Comment: "I remember 'clean'. " - Gus Haynes, The Wire

Comment: I wonder if there is a cleaner solution to this, however I'm sceptical.